# PHP call array value

Tags: php, arrays, variables

First I have these variables:

```
$asd=$current[0]->icon['data']; // -it will print  /ig/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.gif
$icons["/ig/images/weather/rain.gif"][0]; // it will print rain.gif
```

I want to see rain.gif output. I'm trying to do this.

```
echo $icons[$asd][0]; // I will get error.
```

I want to get this output with variables.

```
$icons["/ig/images/weather/rain.gif"][0]; // it will print rain.gif
```

Is the code wrong?

```
echo $icons[$asd][0];
```

Please help.

thanks evryone. sorry for my english.

how can I do this.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to clarify a bit what you need. Do you want to display the gif? Or print the variable's name? Or get the image path+filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

```
echo basename('/ig/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.gif'); // output: mostly_cloudy.gif');
echo basename('/ig/images/weather/rain.gif');          // output: rain.gif
```

Assuming that `$asd` (in your example) is the path to the image and you're just looking for the file name portion).

Though your question is not 100% clear.